# PHP proxy for mp4 videos

Tags: php, mp4

```
<?php
/**
 * proxy.php
 * Acts as a server-side requestor for data on behalf of the client-side, in order to get around the "same-origin" problem
 * (NOTE: there could be a small security risk by doing a naiive REQUEST to pass the proxy URL without POST + SSL and more thorough validation. Only if an attacker knew the location of this script, would there be a chance they can use it as a proxy for attacks to other servers, or this server. For our purposes, it probably is negligible, but for more on how to solve potential issues, see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php or: http://www.virtualforge.de/vmovie/xss_selling_platform_v1.0.php)
 */

$url = $_REQUEST['url']; //URL to grab (again, see NOTE on security above)
if (empty($url)) { $url = "http://dd.weatheroffice.ec.gc.ca/citypage_weather/xml/NB/s0000687_e.xml"; } //make sure we always get some data (default to a Weather feed)

/**
 * getAddress
 * @get the full url of the current page (protocol + host + request URI including parameters)
 * @return string
 */
function getAddress() {
$protocol = $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' ? 'https' : 'http'; /*** check for https ***/
return $protocol.'://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; /*** return the full address ***/
}

//parse the passed in URL using parameterized query object (could add validation here, see: http://www.scriptol.com/how-to/parsing-url.php )
$arr = parse_url(getAddress()); //use PHP convenience function for full address
$parameters = $arr["query"];
parse_str($parameters, $param);

$format = $param['f']; //examples: &f=xml | &f=json | &f=html (for more MIME-Types, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mime_type)
$encoding = $param['e']; //examples: &e=utf-8 | &e=iso-8859-1 | &e=Shift-JIS (for more Character Encodings, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding)
$e = (!empty($encoding)) ? $encoding : "utf-8"; //might want to limit allowed charset/encoding types

header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate'); //force fresh request
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
// Set your return content type, based on the expected response type...
switch ($format) {
case "xml":
case "xsl": 
case "kml":
header("Content-type: application/xml; charset={$e}");
break;
case "geojson":
case "json":
case "rdfjson": case "rdf/json": case "rdf+json": case "jron":
header("Content-type: application/json; charset={$e}");
break;
case "georss":
case "atom":
header("Content-type: application/atom+xml; charset={$e}");
break;
case "rss":
case "rss2": case "rss2.0":
case "rss1": case "rss1.0":
case "rss0.92": case "rss0.91": case "rss0.90": case "feed": case "rdf":
header("Content-type: text/xml; charset={$e}");
break;
case "owl":
case "rdf+xml": case "rdfxml":  
header("Content-type: application/rdf+xml; charset={$e}");
break;
case "swf":
case "flash": case "flv":
header("Content-type: application/x-shockwave-flash");
break;
case "image":
header("Content-type: image/png");
break;
case "svg":
header("Content-type: image/svg+xml");
break;
case "audio": case "ogg":
header("Content-type: audio/ogg");
break;
case "mp3":
header("Content-type: audio/mpeg");
break;
case "video": case "webm":
header("Content-type: video/webm");
break;
case "mp4":
header("Content-type: video/mp4");
break;
case "xhtml":
header("Content-type: application/xhtml+xml; charset={$e}");
break;
case "xslt":
case "html":
case "html5":
header("Content-type: text/html; charset={$e}");
break;
default:
header("Content-type: text/plain; charset={$e}"); //could be any other plaintext format (including: CSV, TSV, conf, ini, rtf, txt, dat, n3, turtle, JSONp etc...)
break;
}

try {
// Get remote content/data (NOTE: your hosting provider may not allow fopen, if not you can request they allow for your VPS...if still not, we can use file_get_contents or CURL lib instead)
$handle = fopen($url, "r");

// some content/data was received, then read & return
if ($handle) {
while (!feof($handle)) {
$buffer = fgets($handle, 4096);
echo $buffer;
}
fclose($handle);
}
}
catch (Exception $e) {
print file_get_contents($url);
}
?>
```

I'm from Turkey. And my website for Turkish people.. I wanna to share some videos to my website. But videos I want to share, doesn't accept ip's from Turkey. I'm thinking buy a hosting from UK or France and use this proxy script and add my website like that

[myUKhosting.com/proxy.php?url=http://videosblockedforturkey.com/video.mp4] 
     But there is some problems.. this script is working but it shows codes.. when i try to enter like [http://videosblockedforturkey.com/] it shows html codes.. when i try to enter videos like [http://videosblockedforturkey.com/video.mp4] it shows MP4 codes.. How can I get mp4 video not mp4 codes? Please help me and edit this script :(
Image Link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/adScs.png

Comment: mp4 code, there is no such thing.

Comment: yeah i know that but i mean this.. the source.. http://i.epvpimg.com/b4hve.png